# Should I convince user to use feature

Tags: colleagues, software-development

I was tasked with making a new software for internal use and I implemented a new feature that I think would improve business process accuracy. However the end user doesn't want to use it (thinks it takes too long or not needed).

Should I try to convince them to use it or just let it be? This feature would take 10 minutes longer on a once per week process and they can do other stuff while it's running. However I don't want to force people to use things and it's not really my authority.

Comment: _"However I don't want to force people to use things and it's not really my authority"_ There is your answer.. If your superiors think the software/program should be used internally let them handle it.

Comment: Keep in mind that some people are afraid of getting automated out of a job.

Comment: Why are you implementing features the end user doesn’t want? You should get them interested in the feature *before* you spend time implementing it. When you talk to them about it you might find you’re wrong about their workflow and together you and the user might think of something better that they would be excited to get.

Comment: "I implemented a new feature that I think would improve business process accuracy"  Was this part of your task or something you unilaterally decided to do?

Comment: You should be asking whoever tasked you with building this feature why you're building features the users don't want.

Comment: If the new product feature it solves a problem whose significance they don't rate as high as you do, then "selling it to them" makes you the bearer of bad news. Depending on whether their 'problem' (the defect in business process accuracy) affects you, it may be better to wait until they naturally discover the need, then you will have a good fix ready.

Comment: @PeteW I think sometimes it's good to piss a few people off if it means the better of the business

Comment: tricky when those people are your customers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to document the usage of the functionality clearly. Send the documentation over to the user, and mention that in the case they do want to start using this, they can use the documentation or reach out to you.

It is their choice what to do with it then, but you've done your job. If your boss asks a status update, or asks why it isn't used/done, point them to this email you sent.

Comment: I like this im really shy so documenting it instead of sending it in will be better for all involved instead of me explaining like a PIMP.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't have ownership of this process so you should not convince the user to use the feature - as you say, it's not your place.

But it sounds like it's normal for you to speak direct with your customer so if you are confident it represents a process improvement, you could discuss with them them the problem you were trying to fix and why you think it helps, and get their feedback on why they don't want to use it, and whether there is further change that they would want. Perhaps they don't think the problem you fixed was a problem at all, or perhaps the solution you've provided didn't work as well as you think or adds other problems that mean it's not worth using. Perhaps it was wasted effort, or maybe a small extra tweak turns it into the most useful change they've seen in the last decade - you'll only know by talking to them.

Being able to propose useful changes yourself makes you a more valuable employee than the guy who just takes the next task given to them and does what they're told. Done well it shows initiative and that you have an understanding of your product. But done badly means you spend time on 'hobby' changes when there is higher priority work to be done and you're not usefully productive however hard you work or smart you are. In future make sure you have buy-in from whoever is going to use your change - or whoever in your company/team represents them - that they actually want it before working on it, and agree an appropriate priority with whoever has that authority on your projects. Make sure you're getting at least the basic requirements clear before you work on an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

> I think would improve business process accuracy

You need to sell this to the end user to get their buy in. Explain how it improves accuracy and if there is any benefit to them (for example it may save them time in other areas if someone is chasing them for reporting for example).

Also you may need to sell this to yours and their managers. Put forward the business case of why this feature is good for the business and how the the end user's extra 10 minutes spend using the new feature has an overall benefit to the business. If yours/their manager sees the benefit, then they have the authority to push the end user to use the new feature.